# UITestControl.GetChildren() does not list all the children inside it

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to identify a control inside a div like in the given stack below using CodedUI UITestControl.GetChildren().

```html
<ng-transclude>
  <div class="row ng-scope">...</div>
  <br class="ng-scope">
  <div class="ng-scope">...</div>
  <br class="ng-scope">
  <div class="ng-scope">...</div>
</ng-transclude>
```

When I get the children of the ng-transclude tag in the above example, i am expecting 5 children but codedui is returning only 3. It is missing all the br's.

How to avoid this? I need those Br's as well.

Thanks in Advance.
Pirasanna Ravi

Answer (score 0):

if you are using filter parameters, then rather use search parameters in finding the control.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all children should be of the type HtmlControl. The 
 is not a control. For the list of contols see: [List of Cotrols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.aspx)